Is subscriber mode access possible in a scratch org?
Does anyone know if it possible to configure a scratch org's parameters such that subscriber mode access is allowed? We have several managed packages and sometimes there are issues that we can only reproduce inside a scratch org with the managed packaged. Because we do not have subscriber mode access, we cannot see the debug logs and the issues can be difficult to troubleshoot.
I am able to grant subscriber mode access and I see it in Subscriber Organizations, but I receive the following error when trying to log in:

Subscriber mode access to the scratch orgs used to work, but Salesforce changed something and it stopped working.
